# can not install Ropper with pip on Linux

Tags: python, linux, pip

I am trying to write some script which requires ropper. (install only via pip)
How can i fix this problem?

I am trying to install it on linux, tried to upgrade setuptools, install old version and followed this, only one topic, which i found:
[the link](https://notbe.cn/2019/05/12/zhangpeterx_90139008.html)!

This is the error message:

```
$ pip install ropper

DEPRECATION: Python 2.7 will reach the end of its life on January 1st, 2020. Please upgrade your Python as Python 2.7 won't be maintained after that date. A future version of pip will drop support for Python 2.7.
Collecting ropper
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/94/b1/922dfab5083ff439ce70358c7f3e49185c54e6ea6ee2bb7cd292e63eac06/ropper-1.12.1.tar.gz
Collecting filebytes>=0.9.18 (from ropper)
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/0b/3a/9fc0c62bd74583137a8bbc3c8020d6a8234b9cf8bc1e99fe929688b19093/filebytes-0.9.20.tar.gz
    ERROR: Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    ERROR: Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pip-install-d44HeD/filebytes/setup.py", line 3, in <module>
        from pathlib import Path
    ImportError: No module named pathlib
    ----------------------------------------
ERROR: Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-install-d44HeD/filebytes/
```

Comment: It appears that you are installing a Python 3 version using Python 2 (`pathlib` is from Python 3 stdlib). In the case when the module author forgot to include it as a dependency, I suppose you can try to install a backport from https://pypi.org/project/pathlib2/ and retry.

Comment: I guess that you probably have both Python 2.7 (`python`) and Python 3.x (`python3`) on your machine, and similarly maybe two versions of pip, `pip` and `pip3`...? Check which Python version `pip` uses: `pip --version` should output something like `pip 19.1.1 from /home/user/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pip (python 3.6)`. Maybe try using `pip3`, if it's defined?

Answer (score 2):

`filebytes==0.9.20` release is not compatible with Python 2; the package maintainer already fixed this, but the new version is not yet uploaded to PyPI. Restrict `filebytes` to previous version for now:

```
$ pip install "filebytes<0.9.20" ropper
```

Once next version (0.9.21) is released, you can update it if you want:

```
$ pip install --upgrade "filebytes>0.9.20"
```